# integrating jquery masonry into a zurb foundation grid

Tags: jquery-masonry, zurb-foundation

I'm having issues integrating masonry with a Foundation grid layout. Essentially with  identical width images with varying height, the masonry works as expected but at certain breakpoints the grid only will have a two column layout as opposed to the usual four.

However if you keep minimizing the browser width, the four columns return so it can't be that there isn't the room to display them.

```
var $container = $('#work_grid');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
 $('#work_grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.work_item',
  isAnimated: true,    
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div id="work_grid" class="block-grid four-up">
            <li class="work_item"><img src="stylesheets/images/work1.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="work_item"><img src="stylesheets/images/work2.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="work_item"><img src="stylesheets/images/work3.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="work_item"><img src="stylesheets/images/work4.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="work_item"><img src="stylesheets/images/work5.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="work_item"><img src="stylesheets/images/work6.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li class="work_item"><img src="stylesheets/images/work7.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </div> <!-- /.block-grid four-up -->
    </div> <!-- /.twelve columns -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

[image: Working initially]
[image: now not working]

[image: working again]

Comment: It would be best if you can provide a live link to where this is happening.

Answer (score 14):

To answer your question about *why* your issue is happening:
Unfortunately since integrating masonry and frameworks can be tricky since both are attempting to control the image in completely different ways (Foundation wants to resize and masonry wants to reposition). The best way to tackle this issue is to use a foundation container as the masonry container, the images inside will not resize, but will reposition within the fluid container while **centering the container** to avoid awkward margin issues which appear on the right-side of containers when images cannot be placed into an extra column.

=== **UPDATE** ===

I updated the code base with the most up-to-date Foundation version at the time of this update (5.0.2) in [this github repository](https://github.com/dylanbaumann/Zurb-Foundation-and-Masonry) if you'd like to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much Dylan for taking the time to do this!

Comment: No problem @onjegolders , I was actually just working on this last month! I found your post because I wanted to save any hassle for anyone else trying to figure it out

Comment: Great work @Dylan!  You have saved me hours of work.  I am new to both Masonry and  and Foundation and was struggling to understand the differences and to make a choice between them.  So thanks!

Comment: @leeTee You're very welcome! I thought other people would like a jump start on it since it can be overwhelming if you immediately jump into trying to mesh the two together

Comment: hey dylan, do you know how to make it work with foundation 5 ?thank you

Comment: @Dylan thank you. I am migrating from Bootstrap to Foundation. Bootstrap sites looks all the same.

Comment: @ytsejam I've updated my repository with Foundation 5.0.2 in the example, so you're more than welcome to fork it!

Comment: @Dylan I am checking nice news.