# Integrating Zurb Foundation Clearing with Masonry

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, jquery-masonry

I am building a portfolio for my wife and I am just starting acquiring sufficient knowledge to make it happen.
I am using Zurb Foundation as a starting point and trying to combine the Desandro masonry with Clearing to showcase her work.
How can I combine the two to make it work using thumbnails? I have posted two examples of markup structure.

Here is the markup for Masonry:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="container" class="large-12 columns transitions-enabled large-centered clearfix">
  <div class="box col2" style="background: #2ADfFE"><h4>Ilustracions</h4></div>
  <div class="box col2"><a href="#"><img src="img/1.jpg"/></a>
  </div>
```

Here the one for Clearing:

```
<ul class="clearing-feature" data-clearing>
    <li class="clearing-featured-img">
      <a href="img/1.jpg" alt="1">
        <img class="thumbs" data-caption="1" src="img/thumb/1.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If anyone has an idea it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
C

Answer (score 0):

The way you have to integrate Zurb's Foundation with Desandro's Masonry is a little tricky, there was a similar question asked which I have provided an answer to as well as a link to a premade integration of the two hosted on github

[integrating jquery masonry into a zurb foundation grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338954/integrating-jquery-masonry-into-a-zurb-foundation-grid/15912865#15912865)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
I have since figured it out and I am using the `clearing-featured-img` class to show only the one I want to show. I am not sure it's all perfectly semantic but the page is validated by w3c.
Here is the markup:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="container" class="large-12 columns transitions-enabled large-centered clearfix">
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img"><div class="box col2"><a href="img/...jpg"><img data-caption="..." src="img...jpg" alt=""/></a>
  </div></li>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img ilu"><div class="box col2"><a href="img/...jpg"><img data-caption="..." src="img...jpg" alt=""/></a>
  </div></li>
```