# Fluid layout within a Zurb Foundation with variable heights

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to layout variable height content all with the same width in a similar way to many of the Tumblr templates -- ie with no blank spaces vertically between them.

Is there a way to do this within Zurb Foundation  (I know its a grid system)

In other words I want:

```
XXX YYY AAA
XXX YYY AAA
XXX     AAA
XXX ZZZ
XXX ZZZ BBB
    ZZZ BBB
CCC ZZZ
CCC ZZZ DDD
CCC ZZZ DDD
```

whereas I get:

```
XXX YYY AAA
XXX YYY AAA
XXX     AAA
XXX
XXX

CCC ZZZ BBB
```

Basically I would like the opposite of what most people ask for when they want equal column heights -- I would like the content to fill in the whites paces.

James

Comment: Assuming that you are using rows, put x,y and a in one row and c,z and b in another. This will clear the floated elements.

Comment: The issue is the content is database driven and will vary in length.  What are want to do it remove the white space that appears between the rows in a grid system.

Comment: Oh, my fault. I read it backwards. Unfortunately Foundation does not come with this feature, let alone CSS in general (for now). You would be best off using something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @esswilly for the link to Masonry.   Another search on stackoverflow came up with the solution on how to make Masonry work with Foundation.

Details are at [integrating jquery masonry into a zurb foundation grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338954/integrating-jquery-masonry-into-a-zurb-foundation-grid) and work a treat.